# Which one is the best way to manage an iOS project with multiple target?

Tags: ios, git, git-flow

We have an iOS project with multiple targets that use Git as source control. Some features belong to a specific target and the other features are common in all targets. We have to consider and manage this issue. As far as I know, with considering git-flow we have two options to manage our project.

- **The first option is:** we divide each target to separated branches and each branch has two branches (Master and Develop) so we can use cherry-pick to move our commits from one branch to another one.
- **The second option is:** we just use one branch with multiple targets as a Master branch. So we should create a config file to specify which feature belongs to which target. The main question is which one is the best way for our problem?

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

**PS:**

1) Two developers are working on this project.
2) Considering CI/CD tools such as Jenkins for building and releasing our apps.
3) We never use the Storyboard on this project at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly I think you’d like to hide some features behind the beta/develop flag, rather than the release flag. One way which I personally use is having a `Feature` class for all of the targets and whenever a feature is still on develop it would be hidden behind a beta flag.

I hope this article by John Sundell about feature flag helps https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/feature-flags-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks, your link has had very useful for me.